# Spring Integration service activator suspend handler function with generics

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to use Kotlin suspend functions as my service activator handler method. The service activator is set up in the following way:

```
interface WorkflowStep<T, E> {

    @ServiceActivator
    suspend fun handle(message: Message<T>): E {
        // Pre-processing of the message that is repeated before every workflow step
        return stepLogic(message)
    }

    suspend fun stepLogic(message: Message<T>): E
}

class ExampleStep() : WorkflowStep<String, String> {

    override suspend fun stepLogic(message: Message<String>): String {
      // Processing
    }
}
```

I tried using the service activator from an `IntegrationFlow` like this `handle(exampleStep, "handle")`. The issue is that the message that is received in the `handle` suspend function has the following payload type: `class reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume` instead of `String`. When declaring a `@ServiceActivator` method with an input parameter of `Message<String>` type instead of `Message<T>` it receives the correct type, so I assume this is related to the generic types used. Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that with `Message<String>` you receive a value of that `Mono`, but not a `Mono.toString()`? There is just no way in the framework to assume your expectations between `Mono` type and `String`, so you probably need to add extra step in between the producer of that `Mono` and this `@ServiceActivator`. The easiest way is to mark your producer as an `async = true` and that `Mono` will be subscribed and its value emitted to the output channel.

**UPDATE**

Thank you for more info about your problem.

So, I wrote this simple application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class So76960998Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<So76960998Application>(*args)
}

@Configuration
class Configuration {

    @Bean
    fun testFlow(exampleStep: ExampleStep) =
            integrationFlow {
                handle(exampleStep, "handle") { async(true) }
            }

    @Bean
    fun runApplication(@Qualifier("testFlow.input") inputChannel: MessageChannel) =
            ApplicationRunner {
                println(MessagingTemplate()
                        .convertSendAndReceive(inputChannel, "test", String::class.java))
            }

    interface WorkflowStep<T, E> {

        @ServiceActivator
        suspend fun handle(message: Message<T>): E {
            // Pre-processing of the message that is repeated before every workflow step
            return stepLogic(message)
        }

        suspend fun stepLogic(message: Message<T>): E
    }

    @Service
    class ExampleStep : WorkflowStep<String, String> {

        override suspend fun stepLogic(message: Message<String>): String {
            println(message)
            return message.payload.uppercase()
        }

    }
    
}
```

It works as expected and I got a `TEST` in logs after using that `convertSendAndReceive()`.

Pay attention, please, to the `{ async(true) }` configuration of the `handle()` method in the integration flow.

The point is that `suspend` functions are treated as reactive internally by the framework and therefore that `MonoOnErrorResume` is produced as reply. When service activator is marked as `async`, then this `Mono` is subscribed by the framework and its value is emitted to the output channel on demand.

Comment: The thing is that I don't use `Mono` in my code at all. I assume the `MonoOnErrorResume` is coming from the framework itself. The "producer" in this case is a simple `DirectChannel` from which the `integrationFlow` is started. 

As i understand, the framework internally uses `Mono` to implement suspending functions, and the result should be automatically converted, as it happens in the case when i use a `suspend fun handle(message: Message<String>)`. Instead, for `suspend fun handle(message: Message<T>)`, I get the `MonoOnErrorResume` (which has the correct value inside) .

Comment: Please, find an UPDATE in my answer. The generics works as expected in that configuration.